# For which $p$'s is measurable $f$ in $\mathcal{L}^p$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

If we assume that for some measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$, $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{\bar R}$ is measurable, and that $f\in\ \mathcal{L}^p$ for some $p\geq1$, but that $f\not\in\mathcal{L}^{p-\varepsilon}$ for $\forall\varepsilon>0$, then intuitively, it seems logical to assume that $f\not\in\mathcal{L}^q$ for any $1\leq q<p$. Similarly, I would assume that if $f\not\in\mathcal{L}^{p+\varepsilon}$, but $f\in\mathcal{L}^{p}$, then $f\not\in\mathcal{L}^r$ for any $r>p$. Is this actually true? If so, can I prove it somehow? If not, could anyone provide a counterexample, please?
$f\in\mathcal{L}^p$ if it holds that $\int_X|f|^pd\mu<\infty$, to be clear on the definition I am using (not sure if that  might cause any confusion).
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just to add to @WoolierThanThou's answer, and since you're asking yourself these types of questions. For any interval of $p$'s there's a measurable function that belongs to exactly those $L^p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a counter example to the first statement, let $X=\mathbb{N}$, $\Sigma$ be the power set algebra and $\mu$ be the counting measure. Then, defining $f(n)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},$ we have $f\in L^p$ exactly when $p>2$.

For a counter example to the second statement, let $X=[0,1]$, $\Sigma=\mathscr{B}[0,1]$ be the Borel algebra and $\mu$ be the Lesbegue measure. Then, defining $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}},$ we have $f\in L^p$ exactly when $p<2$.

Comment: I'm not sure that we've understood each other, maybe the problem is on my end. In your first example, to which $L^p$ does $f(n)$ not belong?

Comment: $L^{3/2}$ for instance, but it *does* belong to both $L^{5/2}$ and $L^{2+\varepsilon}$ for $\varepsilon$ small. You're right that I should have been more explict that these are the only $L^p$-spaces that the respective $f$'s belong to.

Comment: Alright, but I can't help but notice that what you've laid out does not really demonstrate the property directly, since $3/2<2<5/2$. I guess there is a shorter way of stating my question; is the set of $p\geq 1$ such that $f\in L^p$ an interval?

Comment: Note that that's not the question you asked. You asked whether $f\in L^p\setminus L^{p-1}$ implies $f\not \in L^q$ for $q<p$. I've given you an example that this is not true.

Comment: However, if $p_1<q<p_2$, and $f\in L^{p_1}\cap L^{p_2}$, then $|f|^q\leq |f|^{p_2} 1_{\{|f|\geq 1\}}+|f|^{p_1} 1_{\{|f|<1\}}\leq |f|^{p_2}+|f|^{p_1}$, implying that yes, the $p$'s such that $f\in L^p$ *is* an interval.

Comment: I guess you may have posted your response while I edited my original post slightly. Either way though, I will consider my question answered, thank you.